# Retrieve logged on user name or id in the process running under root

Tags: c, linux

I need to run from a privileged (root) application another application with current logged on user.

`getenv("USER")` and `getenv("LOGNAME")` return "root" in the privileged application. Effective and current user ids are 0.

```
cat /proc/self/status | grep [GU]id:
Uid:    0       0       0       0
Gid:    0       0       0       0
```

I found something close to my needs, `user-1000.slice`, but I would like to avoid using `fscanf` on the file `/proc/self/cgroup`.

```
cat /proc/self/cgroup | fgrep user
9:devices:/user.slice
8:pids:/user.slice/user-1000.slice
1:name=systemd:/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-c1.scope
```

The code bellow outputs 1000 as desired. **Is there any more convenient way or API to get a user name of current UI session from a privileged application?**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int luid = 0;
  char line[100];
  FILE* file = fopen("/proc/self/cgroup", "r");

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    if (sscanf(line, "%*d:pids:/user.slice/user-%d.slice", &luid) == 1)
      break;
  }
  fclose(file);
  printf("Logged on User Id: ");
  luid ? printf("%d\n", luid) : printf("Not found\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: While there is no single 'current user' (as per answer from `AProgrammer`), you might have some information in the process tree that will help you. Can you clarify how do you start the root session from the the 'current user' session (sudo/su/ssh/...). ?

Comment: @dash-o The root app/session is started with pkexec. There's no information in the process tree. The parent process is upstart on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed it lately that the upstart process is running under a log on user, I thought it is running under root. So, my solution below looks better than one with extracting user id from `/proc/self/cgroup`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int uid = -1;
  char line[100];
  pid_t sid = getsid(0);
  sprintf(line, "/proc/%d/status", sid);
  FILE *file = fopen(line, "r");

  while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
    if (sscanf(line, "Uid: %d", &uid) == 1)
      break;
  }
  fclose(file);
  printf("Logged on User Id: ");
  uid != -1 ? printf("%d\n", uid) : printf("Not found\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The is no machine wide notion of "current UI session" under Unix.  It does not make sense as Unix has its origin as a multi-user system, that mean that several people may be logged on at the same time, each with several UI session.  It's the case for me on the machine I'm working one, there are 4 people logged on, 6 UI sessions and about 20 non UI sessions.

There is a database of current logged on people, `/var/run/utmp`.  Maintaining this database is somewhat to the programs discretion (for instance, the version of gnome-terminal I'm using allow to add or not entries in the database).  The database format is described in `utmp(5)`, and there are functions to access it (see `getutent(3)`).  There are programs to display its content (`who(1)` and `w(1)`) and modify it (`sessreg(1)`).

I'm not sure what your purpose is, so it is difficult to recommend an approach.  Ensuring that your display manager add an entry in `utmp` and parsing the result of `who` is probably the easiest but you have to pay attention to assumptions you are making.

Comment: "current UI session" is the session where the root application is running. I have not found a way how utmp may help me. `w`, `wgo` and `sessreg` have tty, that makes them working well.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming that root session was launched with 'pkexec' from a terminal.**

When running pkexec from a termnal, the following process hierarchies is displayed:

```
pstree -p | grep $$

         ...
         |-gnome-terminal-(3295)-+-bash(3302)---bash(93463)-+-grep(93500)
         ...
```

In this situation possible to extract the user based on the following logic:

1. Find the grand parent of the current process: cur_user_pid
2. Depending on the specific setup, might have to go up additional layers, potentially, until detecting a non-root ID.
3. Lookup the user id cur_user_pid

Much easier to do in shell, so if possible, escape to the shell, following the partial example:

```
char buff[50], cur_user[50] ;
int cur_user_pid = 0 ;
sprintf(buff, "x=$(ps -oppid= %d) ; ps -ouid,user= $x", getppid()) ;
FILE *fp = popen(buff, "r") ;
fscanf(fp, "%d %s", &cur_user_pid, curr_user) ;
pclose(fp) ;
```

If not possible to escape to the shell, I believe possible to travel process tree using /proc file system. Per [How to get a grandparents/ancestors process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22159006/how-to-get-a-grandparents-ancestors-process-id), it available in the fourth field of '/proc/[pid]/stat'.